# SQL: Creating Orignial Effective date from list of Date ranges

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following data

```
Mbr_ID|Grp_id|Srt_date|End_date
0001  |A     |1/1/2015|6/1/2015
0001  |B     |6/1/2015|1/1/2017
0001  |C     |1/1/2017|11/17/1858
0002  |A     |1/1/2015|6/1/2015
0002  |B     |1/1/2016|1/1/2017
0002  |C     |1/1/2017|11/17/1858
0003  |A     |1/1/2017|2/1/2017
0003  |B     |2/1/2016|11/17/1858
```

From it I would like to extract the current group a member is on and the original start date of a member where the do not have a lapse in coverage.  Results would be as follows.

```
Mbr_ID|Grp_id|Srt_date|End_date
0001  |C     |1/1/2015|11/17/1858
0002  |C     |1/1/2016|11/17/1858
0003  |B     |1/1/2017|11/17/1858
```

Member 0002  I want the start date of 1/1/2016 as they had a lapse in coverage from 6/1/2015 to 1/1/2016.  As a note the 11/17/1858 is some arbitrary end date our system gives members who are currently active with no end date.

Comment: What is your Oracle version? From 12.1 you might look at [match_recognize](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DWHSG/pattern.htm).

Answer (score 0):

The following gets one row for each period of continuous membership:

```
select mbr_id,
       max(grp_id) keep (dense_rank first order by srt_date desc) as grp_id,
       min(srt_date) as srt_date,
       (case when min(end_date) = date '1858-11-17' then min(end_date)
             else max(end_date)
        end) as end_date
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_end_date = srt_date then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by mbr_id order by srt_date) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(end_date) over (partition by mbr_id order by srt_date) as prev_end_date
            from t
           ) t
      ) t
group by mbr_id, grp;
```

You can filter for the `end_date` being active, if you want the data for the current memberships.

Comment: Thanks! gets me really close to what I need.  If I wanted to put a criteria on the Group ID, to only include members in certain groups, where would I put the 'Where' function for that?  I would want it on the group ID (the grp_id field) that you are choosing withing the statement.

Comment: ** Quick Edit.  I would actually probably join to a table that has the specific group IDs i need.  Just struggling to get the inner join/where function in to still get the results I want

Comment: @dnp2 . . . You would put it in the innermost subquery.